# Change height of eXtplorer's text editor EditArea

Tags: javascript, html, css, file-manager

Does anyone know how to change height of the text editor (EditArea) in eXtplorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the file 'include/edit.php' with a text editor.
2. Search for 'height' (by default, the value is 500).
3. Change this value as you want.
4. Save the file.
5. Reload the 'eXtplorer'

That's it :)